# Convert strings to variable references

Tags: python

I have a list of strings:

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I would like to have a list B of variable references:

```
B = [a, b, c, d]
```

How can I do that?

**Edit1:**

I have

```
df_wgt_dict["Freq"+vars_dict['varName'+str(I)]]
```

here I ranges from 1 to 4.

I want to have a list like below:

```
[df_wgt_dict["Freq"+vars_dict['varName'+str(1)],df_wgt_dict["Freq"+vars_dict['varName'+str(2)],df_wgt_dict["Freq"+vars_dict['varName'+str(3)],df_wgt_dict["Freq"+vars_dict['varName'+str(4)]]
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you mean.

Comment: Do you mean you want to print it out as such a list? If you simply want a list of characters it is impossible. Don't even know a use case where this would be needed.

Comment: Lists contains values, not variables. "Variable" is just a name that points to some value.

Comment: if you do `print(A)` you get the representation of the list which is normally used for debug purposes. If you want a special output you have to write it yourself (like `print('[{}]'.format(','.join(A)))`).

Comment: is there any possibility that I can save that print output to a variable (which ofcourse will be list)

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Where does `A` come from?

Comment: OP has a list of strings where the values denote python variable names. He wants to map the string values to the variables.

Comment: I trying out one optimization program where the input list is dynamic and consists of dataframes as elements.It can be 4 or 5 or more dataframes.These dataframes are values of one dictionary.So I want to create a dynamic list of dataframes based on the number of variables.if it is 4 the list is of 4 dataframes,5 list of 5 etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
A = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
B = []
for s in A:
    temp_storage = exec('%s = %d' % (s, my_value))
    B.append(temp_storage)
```

This will change your list A in list B with variables instead of strings

Comment: Don't recommend `exec` unless you know *why* the question is asked in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this directly. However, if you want to perform some operation with these variables, you can still use the keyword [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) or the function [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). These are two different things, that produce different results, but here you can use on or the other without problems.

For example, this will print `5`

```
a = 5
exec 'print a'
```

A simple trick to do what you want:

```
a = 5
b = 6
c = 2
d = 3

L = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  # the input list

M = list()  # the result list
for e in L:
    exec 'M.append('+e+')'  # or eval('M.append('+e+')')
print M
```

This will print

```
[5, 6, 2, 3]
```

**NB : This will not create a list of variables references, but a list of the values of your variables at the moment you call this. You'll have to call it again if you want updated values.**

Comment: Why do people start to link to Docs.SO? Especially Python comes with a great documentaion.

Comment: In my case,each of the elements in list is dataframe.I am passing this to some optimization function.

Comment: @FullName Docs has good examples, that can be more understandable than official doc for beginners. I'll leave a link for both of them.

Comment: @marupav `a`, `b`, etc. can be of any type. You can do lists of every possible types. I just chose ints so it's easier to understand

Comment: Because `exec` is not save. You should not recommend it until you know what the *real* problem is and if there is not other way to solve it.

Comment: let me try that.I have posted an edit.You can have a look at it.